# How to generate nested dictionary faster than with loops?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested-loops

I would like to know how to create nested dictionnary faster than using simple loops (that can be cumbersome with a lot of data). I used to do the following :

```
list_1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....}
list_2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", ....}
list_3 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 ....}

for element_1 in list_1:
    dico[element_1] = {}
    for element_2 in list_2:
        dico[element_1][element_2]={}
        for element_3 in list_3:
            dico[element_1][element_2][element_3] = {}
```

The problem is that I think that with multiple steps and large amount of data, it could be really slow...

thank you

Comment: (1) What are you trying to achieve by creating 3 layers of empty dictionaries? (2) Have you verified that it is *actually* too slow or do you only *think* it is?

Comment: Your `list_x` variables are actually [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still with loops but faster and shorter:

```
dico = {}
for element_1 in list_1:
    dico1 = dico[element_1] = {}
    for element_2 in list_2:
        dico2 = dico1[element_2]={}
        for element_3 in list_3:
            dico2[element_3] = {}
```

Benchmark results:

```
Round 1  Round 2  Round 3 
  59 ms    58 ms    55 ms  original
  40 ms    41 ms    39 ms  optimized
  46 ms    44 ms    43 ms  U11
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTtitswEPyvp1hSjlhX4fojF8pBXqLQXyEYXyznBLEsJBmSC3n2VCvZVnotpXBnWFlaz86sRkrU2b72svyu9O3W6r4DKzouLIhO9dqOK0KOwtgqhw1ccgYFg5LBisETgzWDNE2vAVAgYFEvGCxecNjj0ODAcWgX9@DSs2WOzkXpYuXiycU6G2Gk4S30WhyErI8JfSbgnkbse6y8@lXba@BH3nGJ7QkJodEAneDbGbGLle@ri7m6iNV/YZinxW5zR/Werpzpyt/p/k05T8u7VjW3g5a@avREuXMRb7z5gCl4mJ9jTjEy5Z9lTfF/LvzM82n/47eLeIbLycXZxdWLnqNYSJziVkJCRIfclfsC@1624kDaQe6NU5/uH4uuM5QmcuheuHaIPMuyUKg131vJjSH8pNz0rjyhBMWQFfU8@9S7GY4IxZyDYU5pIW0yfdlAoGMeklaVrDteVZQEGEVxozhviDXY8na78zurZqWdF9e41rU88MT9ilejd4HkMWmXP/pBNs7EKyyjMzNef80ppfMFQ14G1iDmTajE62DC0HiquK3wF5IEfDBtE14Uvo2JWGDSWikum8TSOTl1uHxYNdAZ190DJBYeIedr6pux2IU19A@HYjm93X4B)):

```
from timeit import timeit

list_1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...}
list_2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", ...}
list_3 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, ...}

def original():
    dico = {}
    for element_1 in list_1:
        dico[element_1] = {}
        for element_2 in list_2:
            dico[element_1][element_2]={}
            for element_3 in list_3:
                dico[element_1][element_2][element_3] = {}
    return dico

def optimized():
    dico = {}
    for element_1 in list_1:
        dico1 = dico[element_1] = {}
        for element_2 in list_2:
            dico2 = dico1[element_2]={}
            for element_3 in list_3:
                dico2[element_3] = {}
    return dico

def U11():
    return {i: {x: {y: {} for y in list_3} for x in list_2} for i in list_1}

# config
funcs = original, optimized, U11
number = 1000

# correctness
expect = original()
for func in funcs:
    result = func()
    print(result == expect, func.__name__)
print()

# speed
tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for r in range(1, 4):
    print(*(f'Round {i} ' for i in range(1, r+1)))
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = timeit(func, number=number) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e6) for t in ts), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: I will refer to the optimized version !

Comment: For inputs of more than approx. 100 items, the dict comprehension from @u12-forward still wins, although the difference is small. To see this, e.g. set `list_1 = list_2 = list_3 = range(100)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one liner nested dictionary comprehension:

```
print({i: {x: {y: {} for y in list_3} for x in list_2} for i in list_1})
```

Output:

```
{1: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}, 2: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}, 3: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}, 4: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}, 5: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}, 6: {'d': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'c': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'a': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'e': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'b': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}, 'f': {40: {}, 10: {}, 50: {}, 20: {}, 60: {}, 30: {}}}}
```

Comment: ...but apart from being neater to look at, this is both semantically and performance-wise the same as a nested loop.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah you have a point, well I expect that my code still would have a subtle effect of performance increasing though.

Comment: @tomalak: A quick `timeit` with different list sizes shows a 15-25% increase in speed for the dict comprehension, on my system.

Comment: @Tomalak It does seem a bit faster, but slower than an optimized loop version (see benchmark in my answer).